# Datadog Logs from Windows Event Viewer

Tags: windows-server-2012, datadog, event-viewer

I am new to DataDog and getting back into working with Windows Servers. I am trying to push Event Viewer logs (Security, System, etc) to Datadog logs. I have been successful in terms of setting it up (used their documentation - https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/win32_event_log/). I am getting logs into my DD for that server for my System and Security:

```
logs:
  - type: windows_event
    channel_path: "System"
    source: "System"
    service: System_Event
  - type: windows_event
    channel_path: "Security"
    source: "Security"
    service: Security_Event
```

I know that you can push items from the Event Viewer to Events in DD by using `Instances` and you can be more granular there. But I want that granularity in the logs sections since we rarely view Events. Right now it is showing me all the items in the logs, success, etc. I am looking to only get the Errors and Warnings piped to the Logs.

Thanks for the help.
D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across the same problem and came up with below config that exclude "Information" event.

```
- type: windows_event
  channel_path: System
  source: System
  service: eventlog
  log_processing_rules:
   - type: exclude_at_match
     name: exclude_information_event
     pattern: ^.*[Ll]evel.*Information.*
```

Vincent